# Where should I post questions about how to model a certain dataset?

Tags: discussion, questions, site-recommendation

I have a problem about how to statistically model a certain scientific dataset. I would describe the properties of this dataset, and explain what I'm trying to model. The idea would be to discuss the proper way to model this data.

What is the best SO site for this question? Is this a proper question for SO?

On one hand, I'm asking for advice from statisticians, where there isn't a straightforward answer. This leads to discussions/recommendations, which doesn't fit SO.

On the other hand, there may be properties of this dataset (and the model discussed) would be useful for other users.

What should I do?

Comment: Well, there's https://stats.stackexchange.com/, but I'm not active on that community and have no idea what's acceptable there. However, you could ask them on their meta and/or browse the existing questions and see if there's any well-received similar ones.